# Need help investigating the behaviour of distinctUntilKeyChanged

Tags: rxjs

I have this code below:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { distinctUntilKeyChanged } from "rxjs/operators";

const personSrc = new BehaviorSubject<any>({
  firstname: "Tom",
  lastname: "Hanks",
  inner: {
    obj: 1
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  const newPerson = { firstname: "Bill", lastname: "Smith", inner: { obj: 1} };
  personSrc.next(newPerson);
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  const newPerson = { firstname: "JJ", lastname: "Smith", inner: { obj: 1} };
  personSrc.next(newPerson);
}, 5000);

// should log
personSrc.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("firstname")).subscribe(console.log);

// shouldn't log
personSrc.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("lastname")).subscribe(console.log);

// shouldn't log
personSrc.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("inner.obj")).subscribe(console.log);
```

I was assume that only first `distinctUntilKeyChanged("firstname")` should log but got `distinctUntilKeyChanged("lastname")` and `distinctUntilKeyChanged("inner.obj")` to log as well. Can you explain why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pipe to `personSrc.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("lastname"))` you are creating a new observable that will instantly emit the value in the behavior subject. Next time the behaviour subject emits it is with a new last name therefore it emits again. The next time it emits the lastname is the same so it doesn't emit. This is what you should expect.

`distinctUntilKeyChanged("inner.obj")` will never work as `inner.obj` is not a key on the object. It will be looking at a property `personSrc['inner.obj']` not `personSrc.inner.obj`.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, distinctUntilKeyChanged } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial',
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' }
});

bs$.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged("inner.obj")).subscribe(console.log);

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial', // hasn't changed so wont emit
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' }
});

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial', // hasn't changed so wont emit
  inner: { obj: 'Updated' } // this isn't the key so wont emit
});

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Updated', // this is the key and has updated so causes an emit
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can use distinctUntilChanged with a compare function. I wrote resolveProperty to get a string based property by splitting up the string on .

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs;

const resolveProperty = (obj, property) =>
  property?.split('.').reduce((result, prop) => result?.[prop], obj);
    
const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial',
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' }
});

bs$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(
    (x, y) => resolveProperty(x, 'inner.obj') === resolveProperty(y, 'inner.obj')
  )
).subscribe(console.log);

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial',
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' } // Doesn't emit
});

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Updated', // Changed but not watching so wont emit
  inner: { obj: 'Initial' } // Doesn't emit
});

bs$.next({
  'inner.obj': 'Initial',
  inner: { obj: 'Updated' } // Will emit
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the source code to distinctUntilKeyChanged
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged.ts
you could use my resolveProperty function to create your own distinctUntilPropertyChanged function

Comment: thank you for explanation. is there anyway to workaround that to be able to spy on nested object properties?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use distinctUntilChanged with a compare function